# Getting specific column in Laravel relation returning empty array

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I want to get specific column from Model relation in Laravel, but the relation model returning empty array.

**Eloquent Query**

```
$medicines = Medicine::with(['weightage' => function($query) {
            $query->select('name');
        }])->get(['name', 'description']);
```

**Medicine Modal**

```
public function weightage()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\MedicineWeightage', 'medicine_id');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always need to also select the primary and foreign keys of the table to make the relation work:

```php
$medicines = Medicine::with(['weightage' => function($query) {
   $query->select(['id', 'name', 'medicine_id']);
}])->get(['id', 'name', 'description']);
```

Comment: still it is empty

Comment: $medicines = Medicine::with(['weightages' => function($query) {
            $query->select('id', 'name', 'medicine_id');
         }])->select('id','name', 'description')->get();
this solved my problem

Comment: Oh, right. I forgot the id column in the parent query. Mea culpa!

Comment: Is the any way I do not send primary and foreign keys? This is API I am creating, which one is best with keys or without keys?

Comment: You can remove them from the collection via `->pluck(['name', 'description'])`. If you don't need them, there's no reason to expose them to the client.

Comment: ->get()->pluck(['name', 'description']); like this?

Comment: Should work with and without calling `get()`